# Realm Swiftで数万件のオブジェクトを保存しても問題ありませんか。

Tags: realm

Realm Swiftの最新版を用いてiOSアプリを開発しています。

30個程度のプロパティを持ったオブジェクトを、最大で5万件程度書き込むようなものを検討しているのですが、Realmのパフォーマンス的には問題ないでしょうか。
保存件数が多すぎてデータベースに何かしらの問題が発生することは、考えられますか。
あるいは、5万件程度では全く問題にはならないのでしょうか。

扱うオブジェクトのプロパティは`Int`型か`String`型が多く、`String`型に格納されるものは最大でも256バイト程度です。
一度に5万件書き込むのではなく、アプリを使っているうちに上限の5万件に達するということです。
各レコードの上書きや削除、検索は何度も行われます。

手持ちのiOSデバイスで試してみたところ、問題なく動作していますが、長期間アプリを使用しても問題ないかどうかは確信が持てなかったため質問させて頂きました。

これに付随する質問ですが、保存件数が多くなる場合、データモデルのプロパティ数はなるべく減らした方が良いのでしょうか。
例えば`Bool`型のプロパティが8個ある場合、可能であれば`Int`型の下位8ビットを使って保存するような工夫をするべきですか。
あるいはプロパティ数も数十個程度なら問題にはならないのでしょうか。

素人質問で恐縮ですが、何卒宜しくお願い申し上げます。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Realmの岸川です。そのくらいの件数なら何ら問題になることはありません。プロパティの持ち方も普通にBool型で複数持つほうが分かりやすく、クエリとしても使いやすいのでおすすめです。
注意点としてできるだけRealm のResultsをArrayなどにコピーすることは避けてください。Realmが持つ遅延ロードなどの機能が失われるので気にされてるパフォーマンスに影響します。